# Solve integrals using residue theorem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta }{2+\cos\theta}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x }{(1+x)^6} dx$$

My problem is that I don't know how to start solving these integrals, or how to convert them into usual types that can be solved.

Comment: Add some more details to the question describing what exactly you are asking. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you required to use residues?

Comment: Yes, I have to use residues.

Comment: For the second integral is it $(1+x)^{6}$ or is it $1+x^{6}$? Just asking.

Comment: The exponent is applied to the whole expression.

Comment: I will have to agree with @BillMoustakas for the second one. For the integral to be suitable to be compute by using the Residue theorem, it must have $1+x^6$. Check [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344030/evaluate-the-following-integration-below/1344150#1344150) for a very similar question $\int_0^\infty x^2/(1+x^6)$ instead, but you can solve it just as I did there changing the $x^2$ just for $x$.

Comment: I'll check the expression for the integral as soon as possible. But this one can't be solved? Maybe using logarithms?

Comment: @dralion94 That's one way, incorporating a logarithm. Consider $$\int_{K} \frac{z\log z}{(1+z)^6}\,dz,$$ where $K$ is a standard keyhole contour. Another option is to consider $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{(1+x)^6}\,dx$$ for non-integral $\alpha$ and taking the limit as $\alpha \to 1$.

Comment: I have checked the integral I have to calculate and it is with $(1+x)^{6}$

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you explain more how to do it?

Comment: Do you know how a keyhole contour looks?

Comment: Yes, it's like a circle with zero out

Comment: @DanielFisher I will be more inclined to use $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{(1+x^6)}dx $$ for $0<\alpha<1$. OP If Daniel does not do it soon, I'll put another answer covering this later in the afternoon

Comment: Dear @dralion94 First of all welcome to the MSE site. I see that, although you have already asked 3 question in this site and received answers in all three of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second integral:

Note first that this integral is easily done by recognizing that $x=(1+x)-1$, so the integral is really

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x)^5} - \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x)^6} = \frac14-\frac15=\frac1{20}$$

One may also use the residue theorem.  However, one must choose an appropriate contour and integrand.  In this case, a useful contour integral to consider is

$$\oint_C dz \frac{z \log{z}}{(1+z)^6} $$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour of outer radius $R$ and inner radius $\epsilon$ about the positive real axis.  The contour integral is then equal to

$$\int_{\epsilon}^R dx \frac{x \log{x}}{(1+x)^6} + i R \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{R e^{i \theta} \log{(R e^{i \theta})}}{(1+R e^{i \theta})^6} \\ + \int_R^{\epsilon} dx \frac{x (\log{x}+i 2 \pi)}{(1+x)^6} + i \epsilon \int_{2 \pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\epsilon e^{i \phi} \log{(\epsilon e^{i \phi})}}{(1+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^6}$$

As $R \to \infty$, the second integral vanishes as $\log{R}/R^4$.  As $\epsilon \to 0$, the fourth integral vanishes as $\epsilon^2 \log{\epsilon}$.  Thus, the contour integral is, in this limit

$$-i 2 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x}{(1+x)^6} $$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $x=e^{i \pi}$.  (Note how important it is to get the argument correct.)  The residue at this pole is

$$\frac1{5!} \left [ \frac{d^5}{dz^5} \left ( z \log{z} \right ) \right ]_{z=e^{i \pi}} = -\frac{3!}{5!} $$

Putting this altogether, we get that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x}{(1+x)^6} = \frac1{20}$$

which agrees with the above.

Comment: Well, we'd be pretty screwed if it didn't agree, wouldn't we?

Comment: @DanielFischer: yeah, just think of all the rep we'd lose.  ;)

Comment: Heh, good thing I'm a moderator, I wouldn't lose any privileges ;)

Comment: Thank you. One question, how does the denominator from the integral pass to $z\log z$

Comment: @dralion94: you mean numerator?  In that case, we the introduction of the log in the contour integral is a standard technique.  It exploits the log's multivaluedness so that the original integrand is returned.

Comment: @RonGordon Excuse me Sir for the out of context question, but I find the notation 
$$
\int dx \ f(x)
$$ 
extremely odd. What is the context of this one? I mean is it use by engineers or something like that? I have always read math books and always seen the usual notation
$$
\int f(x) \ dx
$$

Comment: @LeoSera: I get this question from time to time.  It is an antiquated physics notation that I rather like for its clarity - it ties the integration variable to its integral.  It's very useful for double integrals (and multiple integrals for that matter), so I really picked up the habit studying Optics.

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you very much for your answer. Every day we can learn something new !!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint for the First one** First compute 
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2 + \cos\theta}=\int_0^{2\pi}R(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) d\theta
$$
Where $R$ is the rational function given by $$R(x,y)=\frac{1}{2+x}$$
**How to do this using the residue theorem?** Put $z=e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$, thus 
$$
\cos(t)=Re(z)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}, \ \\ \sin(t)=Im(z)=\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}, \\ dz=ie^{it} dt=iz \ dt \Longrightarrow dt=\frac{1}{iz}dz
$$
Then $I$ can be seen as a contour integral, solve it by using residues 
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}R(\cos(t), \sin(t)) dt= \int_{|z|=1} R\left(\frac{z+1/z}{2}, \frac{z-1/z}{2i} \right)\frac{1}{iz}dz
$$
Hence in your case the integral you will compute is
$$
I= \int_{|z|=1} \left(\frac{1}{2+\frac{z+1/z}{2}} \right)\frac{1}{iz}dz = \frac{2}{i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2+4z+1}
$$
which can be easily obtain by the residue theorem!

**Finally:** Note that 
$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2 + \cos\theta}=\frac{I}{2}
$$
and hence your result follows by computing the next integral 
$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2 + \cos\theta} = \frac{1}{i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2+4z+1} 
$$

**Spoiler Solution**

> Since $z^2+4z+1=(z-(\sqrt{3}-2))(z-(-\sqrt{3}-2))$ and $z_0=\sqrt{3}-2$ is the only root inside the contour $|z|=1$, then by the residue theorem we have $\displaystyle \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2+4z+1} = 2\pi i \left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)=i \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$. Hence we get that the final result is $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2 + \cos\theta}  =\frac{1}{i} \times i \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Thank you!!! The problem was I didn't consider the integral between 0 and pi as twice the integral i wanted to calculate.

Comment: @dralion94 You are welcome! I've just added a spoiler result in case you want to check your solution.

Comment: @dralion94 As I told you in the comments, for the second integral, it is most probable that the denominator is $1+x^6$, if that is the case I am sure my answer [in this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344030/evaluate-the-following-integration-below/1344150#1344150) will help you on how to calculate it by using the residue theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for the first one:**
Consider the function $$f(z)=\dfrac{2}{z^{2}+4z+1}$$ and find its poles. Then use the known formula for residues:
*Under the assumption that f has a pole of order $m$ at $z_{0}$, 
$$Res(z_{0},f) = \dfrac{1}{(m-1)!} \lim_{z \to z_{0}} \dfrac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}((z-z_{0})^{m}f(z)).$$*
And finally, apply the Residue Theorem.

Comment: Why that function? I don't understand.

Comment: If $z = e^{i\theta}$, then $f(z)dz = d\theta/(2+\cos\theta)$, maybe with a factor $i$ in there.

Comment: We seek to make a substitution of $z = e^{it}$. Now, recall that $\cos t = \frac{1}{2} (e^{it}+e^{-it})= \frac{1}{2} (z + \frac{1}{z})$ and that $\frac{dz}{dt} = iz, dt= \frac{dz}{iz}$. Then we apply the above to the given function that contains $\cos t$.

Comment: I see. Where I got stuck was before reaching that f(z).